# Building a great dashboard app in WPF -- what are the controls available out there?

Tags: wpf, controls, wpf-controls, dashboard

My application collects business data from various sources, aggregates it, groups and filters, and needs to display it. Pretty uncommon, right? =)

The point is that I already have a "drill-down" UI, so the Services and Operations people can find their data in the tree view and do their job. But now I also need a shiny high-level dashboard view for the Big Bosses to oversee their whole Kingdom. I guess that should be exactly where the WPF's strength is...

I'm looking at [the Dynamic Dashboards website](http://www.dynamicdashboards.net/) for example and I'd like to know, if there are similar controls available for WPF? Or any other dashboard controls you can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My decision was to take the DragDockPanel from the [Blacklight](http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight) project. It's both WPF and Silverlight-enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [WPF Dashboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2006/06/14/631136.aspx) demo. It comes with source code.
Also the [WPF Dashboard](http://www.codeplex.com/dashboarding/) project on codeplex.
The [Infragistics Dashboard](http://labs.infragistics.com/silverlight/faceout/) demo is nice as well.

Comment: links do not work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old question.. I wanted to put an answer out there for anyone else who is in search of a dashboard like control that isn't Blacklight. I thought I'd share the Wpf Dashboard Control I created. I couldn't find anything out there that handled dynamic widgets with varying sizes so I created my own.

You can check it out here:
https://github.com/DustinBryant/WpfDashboardControl